# How do I create functioning time conditional in python trading model?

Tags: java, c#, python, c++, python-3.x

I am trying to create a trading model, which I want to execute a trade after a certain time. How do I run the console, and have the orders execute at the specific time? Please show an example of code implementation?

`localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
 if localtime >"time":
    #execute order`

Comment: use timedelta(). Just give it a search and you will be able to figure it out.

Comment: what do you mean by "after a certain time"? Is that time duration from when the program is executed or it is timeline (eg: 2pm, 3pm) ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest implementation would be to use [threading](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/). Open a thread that checks the time against your condition every second or so, like

```
while (localtime < time_to_execute):
    time.sleep(1)
    localtime = (refresh the local time value)
*some code to execute a trade*
```

The linked resource has plenty of information on how to open and join threads, so you can set it up to run as you would like (continuous, exiting after the trade, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Not the best, but still work. Please advise if there is a better way. Thanks.

Method: The Order_execution_function goes first since that will hold the code to run the conditional orders. Yet to run the code at a specified time period, the execution conditionals (if statements, price>200...) must be wrapped in a Time_Conditional function, so that the execution code will only be read if the Time_Conditional function is satisfied, which will then allow the Order_execution_function to execute.

```
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer

    def Order_execution_function(self):

         x = datetime.today()
         y = x.replace(year=2019, month=7, day=26, hour=15, minute=36, second=15, microsecond=0)
         delta_t = y - x
         secs = delta_t.seconds + 1

              def Time_Conditional(): 
                   #execute code, if statements...
                   #execute code, if statements...
                   #execute code, if statements...

         t = Timer(secs, Time_Conditional)
         t.start()
```